# Issues detecting textboxes that get generated via a template

Tags: testing, aurelia, telerik-test-studio

I am trying to record UI tests for an Aurelia App. I am using Telerik Test Studio and it has issues detecting the textboxes that get generated via a template.

If I use straight HTML in the template e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

That is easily detected and recorded and playback of the test can enter info into that field

In a template if I have textboxes resembling

```
<textbox name="patientLastName" size="small" editing.bind="editing" if.bind="!demographics.lastName.hidden" required.bind="demographics.lastName.required" label.bind="demographics.lastName.name" value.bind="patient.details.lastName"></textbox>
```

The template works but I get html resembling

```
<input class="form-control au-target" type="text" value.bind="value" disabled.bind="!editing" au-target-id="143">
```

This doesn't appear to be outputting any html attributes/properties that Test Studio can latch onto. How would I alter a textbox so that it is detectable by Test Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that Telerik Test Studio inspects the page too early and that it cannot find elements that are dynamically added? Replace `if.bind` by `show.bind` to see if it works.